# Dict of dataframes in Shared Memory

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, shared-memory, ray

For a data aggregation app I have a dict of dataframes where the keys are for example EURUSD-Deriv-S1, EURUSD-Deriv-S15, EURUSD-Deriv-M30, EURUSD-Vantage-S1 etc. The dataframes size are at the start of the program dynamic till the moment that for example each dataframe exists of 1000 rows. Dataframes itself are pandas frames (the classic ohlc approach)

I want to use another process, literary another program to read (only read) those dataframes out of memory an do processing on them.

As the size of the dataframes is at first dynamic the memory allocated to it is dynamic too, and using the shared memory aproach seems to miss some pieces.

Is there a way to allocate fixed size chunks of continues memory with the sharedmemory manager ? If so I could calculate the max size that dict will grow and allocate at start the max size of that dict, putting it in sharedmem and letting a process read it out.

Can the shared memory aproach do something like that or are there other ways to achieve this (like using ray) ?

---

Edit : I tried preallocated numpy arrays in a dict instead of dataframes but for some reason python throws away my dict of numpy's.

Example :

```
            symbolinfo = order[0]+"|"+order[7]+"|"+order[8] # symbolname + company + login

            if (symbolinfo) not in symbollist:
                symbollist.append(symbolinfo)

                # Flags for closing candles or not                          # timeframelist = ['C15S', 'C1M', 'C5M', 'C15M', 'C1H', 'C4H', 'R1', 'R2']
                flags_dict[symbolinfo] = pd.DataFrame(columns=timeframelist)
                flags_dict[symbolinfo] = flags_dict[symbolinfo].append(beginflags, True)

                for i in range(len(timeframelist)):
                    key_name = symbolinfo+'|'+timeframelist[i]
                   
                    # Setup numpy dataframes with fixed length from numpyrowspertimeframe[i]
                                                                            # rowspertimeframe = [ 15*4*60*24*2, 1*60*24*3, 5*20*24*4, 1*4*24*4, 1*24*10, 4*6*20, 1, 1]
                    numpyframes_dict[key_name] = np.zeros((rowspertimeframe[i],12), dtype=np.float64)
                    sharedmemorynamesdict[key_name] = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=numpyframes_dict[key_name].nbytes, name=prefix+key_name)

                    # Test line at end of numpy arr
                    new_numpy_line = [ -1, -2, -4, -2, -4, -1, -6, -7, -2, -3, 2, 0 ]
                    numpyframes_dict[key_name][-1, :] = new_numpy_line

                    print ('KN : '+key_name)
                    print (numpyframes_dict[key_name])
```

Till here all good, the numpyframes_dict exists, is populated and preallocated.

```
            spread = float(order[1]) - float(order[2])

            start_time = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()  #"almost"
            time_      = time.time() * 1000             # with higher precision


            for i in range(len(timeframelist)):
                dfname = symbolinfo+'|'+str(timeframelist[i])
                print ('DF : '+dfname)

                if (timeframelist[i][0] == 'C'):
                    if (flags_dict[symbolinfo].at[0,timeframelist[i]] == True) and (time_ >= int(epoch)):
                        print ("\n[ ==> Opening "+timeframelist[i]+" frame for "+dfname+" <== ]")

                        ticks = 1

                        print (numpyframes_dict)

                        new_numpy_line = [ time_, float(order[2]), float(order[2]), float(order[2]), float(order[2]),
                                                  float(order[1]), float(order[1]), float(order[1]), float(order[1]),
                                                  float(order[3]), ticks, 0 ]

                        numpyframes_dict[key_name][-1,:] = new_numpy_line

                        print ("New Numpy line : \n")
                        print (new_numpy_line)

                        print ("np line in loop : \n")
                        print (numpyframes_dict[key_name])
```

In the second loop the preallocation is gone, in fact the whole numpy arrays are gone and exists solely of a single row.

So I search a way to preallocate a dynamic dict of numpy's. Shared memory could be a way, caching too.
Or if someone knows another aproach ....

Comment: It looks like the typical use case for a database like Redis. I don't think you can share object in memory with other programs. You can sahre object within a single python program using multiprocessing.Process and multiprocessing.Manager .

Comment: I semi agree, altough redis is way too overkill for my needs. 
If there's a way to assign a continuous piece of memory for above mentioned variables then the only thing I have to do is send a pointer to the memory chunk of that specific vars to the other program which only reads them.
Should the other program also need write capabilities I agree with the redis suggestion.

Comment: As far I know (I know very little), python is not equipped for low-level memory allocation. You could write something in C and then wrap it. But I would let the Manager do the magic. Why are you concern about the memory allocation?

Comment: Reading memory the low-level way without the intervenance of a manager is much faster. In a later stadium the portability to other programming languages and exchanges of variables is easier. One could serialize, pickle, pack or whatever variables and send them for example over a zmq socket, but that's slow. Reading memory the low-level way if one knows the memory structs of the variables ànd if its continious is extremely fast. memory doesn't get fragmentated and less chance on memleaks. It's a technique which was quite common on some architectures in the 90's and blazingly fast.

Comment: Have you tried caching it? But in general, if you want a low-level management of the memory, Python is not the right language for the job.

Comment: Edited the question a bit, to elaborate more. Caching could be a solution, I'll check it out.

Comment: Resolved : typo error : key_name in the second code paste  needs to be dfname, so stupid :(